# Ubuntu Touch - access USB serial for Arduino

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, tty, arduino

I have a BQ Aquaris M10 FHD on which I need to plug an Arduino board over USB. I can I access the serial port of my tablet ?

When I do

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

It return nothing.

When I check the syslog when I plug it, I can see some `[MUSB]musb_hub_control` but nothing about a `ttyUSB`

ls -la /dev/tty give me  a bunch of tty from `tty0 -> tty63, ttyGS0 -> ttyGS7, ttyMT0 -> ttyMT3, ttyp0 -> ttypf`

When I do (saw on another answer) `ll /sys/class/tty/*/device/driver` I get :

```
 /sys/class/tty/ttyMT0/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/mtk-uart/
 /sys/class/tty/ttyMT1/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/mtk-uart/
 /sys/class/tty/ttyMT2/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/mtk-uart/
 /sys/class/tty/ttyMT3/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/mtk-uart/
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Most of the serial port drivers are not built into the kernel on the BQ (and many other manufacturers) phones/tablets. This is true whether you're running Android or Ubuntu on the device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is absolutely no option to be able to use it?

Comment: Not without rebuilding the kernel with extra options enabled and re-flashing (which may be problematic due to kernel size versus partition sizes and the boot loader).

Comment: You mean transposing this answer : http://askubuntu.com/a/824604/409370  to this kernel : https://github.com/bq/aquaris-M10-FHD   ???

Comment: Yes and no. I would say it's a bit more complicated than simply grabbing the kernel source tree and enabling those options, as I'm not entirely sure if that tree has the patches and config needed for Ubuntu, and as I said previously, there will be concerns about size of kernel versus boot loader and partitioning.